# In wordpress how to identify physical page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress but my senior gave me a project for code review but i could not find the phsical page by the url.

so i want know how to find a page which shows on url.

In admin side there are no. of pages so how to identify the page.

Comment: Wordpress does not use "physical pages", any page you see uses a template like content-page.php / header.php / footer.php. all the pages content is kept within the database and is loaded out dynamically. You can edit the pages content in WordPress page editor in the post section. If some pages have the same title you can always go off the slug used.

Comment: my question for custom template means it calls which template.

Comment: That depends on your theme.

Comment: Thanks @JamieSterling